# Javascript Text Expander

Tags: javascript, text, autocomplete, autosuggest, expand

I'm trying to build a really simple form to help me out typing comments (left in our systems after chatting with customers) and get something like "cci" get replaced by "customer called in".

Is this possible with javascript?
I'm asking this because we're not allowed to install any software such as Texter however we are allowed to bring html/js files at work.

Hoping that my problem has been described in full I would like to thank you in advance!

PS: any snippets or links to tutorials are really appreciated!

Comment: I get that you want to have comment snippets from users in a file that after clicking you're going to expand, right?

Comment: I wanted to type into a text area text, such as "cci" for example, and it would get automatically turned into something else. Like textexpander or autocorrect except that I could choose the replacement text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a function which runs at regular intervals and replaces shortcuts in a textarea:

```
update = function() {
    textarea.value = replace-shortcuts-in(textarea.value);
}

textarea.onkeydown = function() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(update, 200);

}
```

Complete working example: http://jsfiddle.net/ucsED/

Comment: This really shed light on this subject